# problem limit of continuous function

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

It looks obvious that if we suppose $\lim a_n=+ \infty,\lim b_n=b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(\cdot,\cdot)$ is continuous, where $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then $$\lim f(a_n,b_n)=f(\lim a_n, \lim b_n) = \lim f(a_n,b)$$. How can we strictly prove this claim?

Comment: It works for finite limit.

Comment: Not sure you can pass the limit on $f$ to $a_n$ since that limit doesn't exist. I'm pretty sure you'd have to just leave it as $lim f(a_n, lim b_n)$

Comment: i am interested in the second equality: $\lim f(a_n,b_n) = \lim f(a_n,b)$

Comment: The middle term is $f(\infty,b).$ What is that supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "obvious" answer is false. Let $f(x,y) = xy.$ Let $a_n = n, b_n = 1/n.$ Then $a_n \to \infty, b_n \to 0=b.$ We have $f(a_n,b_n) = 1$ for all $n,$ while $f(a_n,b)= f(a_n,0) = 0$ for all $n.$

Answer (score 0):

Thanks zhw.

So, it is wrong for the general case, but what about the following case for $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$?
$$f(x,y)=\int_0^x g(s,y)ds$$ where $g(s,\cdot)$ continuous.

Then, let two sequences $a_n \rightarrow + \infty, b_n \rightarrow b$ Doesn't it hold that 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} f(a_n,b_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} f(a_n,b)=\int_0^{+\infty} g(s,b)ds$$